# "Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function" - Beginner Backbone.js Application

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, backbone.js

I'm setting up a pretty simple app with backbone, and I'm getting an error.

```
Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function example_app.js:7
ExampleApp.initialize example_app.js:7
(anonymous function)
```

This is where the error is showing up in Chrome Inspector (init file - example_app.js):

```
var ExampleApp = {
  Models: {},
  Collections: {},
  Views: {},
  Routers: {},
  initialize: function() {
    var tasks = new ExampleApp.Collections.Tasks(data.tasks);
    new ExampleApp.Routers.Tasks({ tasks: tasks });
    Backbone.history.start();
  }
};
```

Here's my tasks index.haml file

```
- content_for :javascript do
  - javascript_tag do
    ExampleApp.initialize({ tasks: #{raw @tasks.to_json} });

= yield :javascript
```

models / task.js

```
var Task = Backbone.Model.extend({});
```

collections / tasks.js

```
var Tasks = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model: Task,
    url: '/tasks'
});
```

routers / tasks.js

```
ExampleApp.Routers.Tasks = Backbone.Router.extend({
    routes: {
        "": "index"
    },

    index: function() {
        alert('test');
        // var view = new ExampleApp.Views.TaskIndex({ collection: ExampleApp.tasks });
        // $('body').html(view.render().$el);
    }
});
```

And here's proof that I'm calling all of the files (I think):

```
<script src="/assets/jquery.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/jquery_ujs.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/jquery-ui.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/underscore.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/backbone.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/backbone-support/support.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/backbone-support/composite_view.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/backbone-support/swapping_router.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/backbone-support.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/example_app.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/easing.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/modernizr.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/models/task.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/collections/tasks.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/views/task_view.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/views/tasks.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/views/tasks_index.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/routers/tasks.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/tasks/index.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/tasks/task.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/application.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Any ideas would be great.  Thanks!

Comment: What's on line 12 of `pears_planner.js`? You don't include that code, but the error message says that's where you problem is.  in fact I'd go so far as to say that is likely the only relevant code for this question.

Comment: Sorry, that should say line 7 (I had some comments in one version).  So that would be the initializer file: `var tasks = new ExampleApp.Collections.Tasks(data.tasks);`

Comment: Wait, so that error is wrong? Because the code you just put in that comment has no mention of `PearsPlanner.initialize` which is where your error appears to be coming from... Help us help you, man... Post the error message, and the code the error message references.

Comment: I'm sorry -- yes, the error was wrong.  I preferred not to have the name of my app in a bunch of places publicly, but I missed that one.  See my edits...

Answer (score 87, accepted):

> Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function example_app.js:7

This error message tells the whole story.  On this line, you are trying to execute a function.  However, whatever is being executed is not a function! Instead, it's `undefined`.

So what's on `example_app.js` line 7? Looks like this:

```
var tasks = new ExampleApp.Collections.Tasks(data.tasks);
```

There is only one function being run on that line. We found the problem! `ExampleApp.Collections.Tasks` is `undefined`.

So lets look at where that is declared:

```
var Tasks = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model: Task,
    url: '/tasks'
});
```

If that's all the code for this collection, then the root cause is right here. You assign the constructor to global variable, called `Tasks`. But you never add it to the `ExampleApp.Collections` object, a place you later expect it to be.

Change that to this, and I bet you'd be good.

```
ExampleApp.Collections.Tasks = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model: Task,
    url: '/tasks'
});
```

See how important the proper names and line numbers are in figuring this out? Never ever regard errors as binary (it works or it doesn't). Instead read the error, in most cases the error message itself gives you the critical clues you need to trace through to find the real issue.

---

In Javascript, when you execute a function, it's evaluated like:

```
expression.that('returns').aFunctionObject(); // js
execute -> expression.that('returns').aFunctionObject // what the JS engine does
```

That expression can be complex.  So when you see `undefined is not a function` it means that expression did not return a function object.  So you have to figure out why what you are trying to execute isn't a function.

And in this case, it was because you didn't put something where you thought you did.

Comment: Never copy code blindly if you are trying to learn. Read and try to understand what you copy.  If you don't know what something is, look it up.  Debugging a program you don't understand is a quick way to make you want to toss your keyboard out a window.

Comment: indeed. In my case, this was caused by a blind copy of $.noConflict().

Comment: Can I put a check like `if (this.props && this.props.callBack) {
              this.props.callBack();
            }`

Answer (score 1):

I have occurred the same error look following example-

```
async.waterfall([function(waterCB) {
    waterCB(null);
}, function(**inputArray**, waterCB) {
    waterCB(null);
}], function(waterErr, waterResult) {
    console.log('Done');
});
```

In the above waterfall function, **I am accepting inputArray parameter in waterfall 2nd function. But this inputArray not passed in waterfall 1st function in waterCB.**

Cheak your function parameters Below are a correct example.

```
async.waterfall([function(waterCB) {
    waterCB(null, **inputArray**);
}, function(**inputArray**, waterCB) {
    waterCB(null);
}], function(waterErr, waterResult) {
    console.log('Done');
});
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

[Joke mode on]

You can fix this by adding this:

https://github.com/donavon/undefined-is-a-function

```
import { undefined } from 'undefined-is-a-function';
// Fixed! undefined is now a function.
```

[joke mode off]

Answer (score 0):

If in MongoDB with async-await , check if you have a missing await before the mongo call.

```
const [assistantError, assistant] = await assistantDb.findOneAssistant({
      _id: assistantId,
    });
```

Here if the await was missing, later when you use assistant, this issue may occur.