# jQuery not working in Wordpress - Works on default

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress

This little snippet here works just fine in JSFiddle, but it does nothing when I put it in with the  tabs within a PHP file for a WordPress button. I currently have standard JavaScript on it to open a popup dialog with "Ok" & "Cancel" but I'd like to use "Yes", "No" & "Cancel" instead.

What's the issue here?

http://jsfiddle.net/vvjj8/617/

HTML

```
<li class="level3 item578"><a id="btnOpenDialog" value="Confirm Dialog Box" href="#"><span>ArmA 2</span></a>

</li>
<div id="dialog-confirm"></div>
```

jQuery

```
function fnOpenNormalDialog() {
$("#dialog-confirm").html("Do you have Play WithSix installed?");
// Define the Dialog and its properties.
$("#dialog-confirm").dialog({
    resizable: false,
    modal: true,
    title: "ArmA 2",
    height: 250,
    width: 360,
    buttons: {
        "Yes": function () {
            $(this).dialog('close');
            window.location.href = "http://www.fogamers.com/arma2.php";
        },
            "No": function () {
            $(this).dialog('close');
            window.open('http://play.withsix.com/', '_blank');
        },
            "Cancel": function () {
            $(this).dialog('close');
        }
    }
});

}
$('#btnOpenDialog').click(fnOpenNormalDialog);
```

Errors

```
Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function (index):76
(anonymous function) (index):76
f.event.dispatch jquery.min.js:3
h.handle.i

Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function widgetkit-dd62f244.js:13
(anonymous function) widgetkit-dd62f244.js:13
o jquery.js?ver=1.7.2:2
p.fireWith jquery.js?ver=1.7.2:2
w jquery.js?ver=1.7.2:4
d

Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function (index):203
(anonymous function) (index):203
o jquery.min.js:2
p.fireWith jquery.min.js:2
e.extend.ready jquery.min.js:2
c.addEventListener.B
```

Comment: Once you put in tabs did you get any errors ? in your browser console?

Comment: Errors updated in first post.

Comment: to get rid of this error check this [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13502733/uncaught-typeerror-undefined-is-not-a-function-beginner-backbone-js-applica]

Comment: Resolved by looking through the Developers Menu, it was already calling another version of jQuery.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wordpress uses [jQuery noconflict mode](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script#jQuery_noConflict_Wrappers). Try replacing all the `$` in your code with `jQuery`.

```
function fnOpenNormalDialog() {
  jQuery("#dialog-confirm").html("Do you have Play WithSix installed?");
  ...
```

Comment: This did it, can't accept an answer yet though.

The errors were resolved by removing a conflicting jQuery script.

Answer (score 2):

What cpilko said is valid, but if you prefer to use the `$` variable in your code (it can be easier for multiple reasons) then redefine it when you call your jquery like so:

```
<script>
 jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

  // you can now use the $ variable
  $("#dialog-confirm").html("Do you have Play WithSix installed?");

 )};

</script>
```