# Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function for "onclick="this.firstChild.play()"

Tags: javascript, html

Why am I getting "**Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function**" error:

```
<div class="mainBox">test Text&nbsp;<a onclick="this.firstChild.play()">
     <audio src="sounds/audio1.mp3"></audio>
     <img class="audioPlayer" src="images/play.jpg"></a>
</div>
```

Comment: Oh, and the answer is of course "because you're trying to call a function that doesn't exist" !

Comment: possible duplicate of ["Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function" - Beginner Backbone.js Application](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13502733/uncaught-typeerror-undefined-is-not-a-function-beginner-backbone-js-applica)

Comment: The first child of that `<a>` might be a text node. Also putting an `<audio>` tag inside an `<a>` tag doesn't seem like valid markup, but I'm not sure about that.

Comment: The error is clear.  Something undefined cannot be a function.

Comment: @Pointy - was just testing, and that's actually it.

Comment: @t.niese OK; my uncertainty was based on the concern that the audio element has (?I think) some interactive behavior (like a pause button?) but if it's not considered "interactive" formally then I guess it's OK.

Comment: @Pointy Sorry I was wrong about the terminology with the _flow content_  I mixed that, but as `a` is transparent and `audio` and `img` are _regular_  elements that don't require a special parent, it is valid to wrap `a` around both, it would just influence the _content categories_ of `a`.

Comment: @t.niese well according to the HTML5 spec, `<audio>` is interactive if it has the "controls" attribute, and `<a>` cannot have any interactive content. However a plain `<audio>` as in this question should be OK.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As @Pointy [said](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24353003/1529630#comment-37653658), there is a line break and tabulation between `<a>` and `<audio>`, so `this.firstChild` is that text node.

You can fix it using

```
this.firstElementChild
```

which will be the first element child instead of the first node child.